# Calculate changed lines same as vscode source control using git diff

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, git-diff

I need to calculated changed lines same way as vscode source control. For example,

[image]

I need to get data in next format:

*Line 1 deleted*

*Lines 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 - deleted*

*Lines 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 - added*

To get git diff data I'm using

```
git diff --unified=0
```

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in an Q&A style. Break it down to individual problems and ask those in separate questions. Tell us also what you actually tried to accomplish a specific task.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has its own diff algorithm implementation. If you want to get exactly the same results, you will need to copy or re-implement it. If you are using Javascript or Typescript, you can use the npm package [vscode-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-diff), which contains the algorithm extracted from VS Code in a zero-dependency library.